# Getting hierarchical data from self referencing table in SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, hierarchical-data, common-table-expression, self-reference

I am using SQL 2005, with existing data of millions of records (so data structure can not be changed) and I'm trying to do the following:

I have some data (following example is from another question and modified a bit to show what I am trying to achieve) in a self referencing table. I need to pull out a tree of results in the following format:

```
Parent
 Child1 of Parent
  Child1 of Child 1
  Child2 of Child 1
 Child2 of Parent
  Child1 of Child 2
```

My actual data goes 9 levels deep - and I have tried to get the result using CTE. However this produces the following:

```
Parent
 Child1 of Parent
 Child2 of Parent
  Child1 of Child 1
  Child2 of Child 1
  Child1 of Child 2
```

Here is an example of the sort of query I am using:

```
create table workshop (
w_id smallint primary key,
p_id smallint,
s_date smalldatetime,
title varchar(100))
go

alter table workshop add constraint fk_wkshp foreign key (p_id)
references workshop(w_id)
go

insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (1, null,
'5/2/2007', 'Parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (2, 1,
'5/3/2007', 'Child 1 of the parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (3, 1,
'5/5/2007', 'Child 2 of the parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (4, 2,
'5/4/2007', 'Child of Child 1')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (5, 2,
'5/5/2007', 'Child 2 of the child of the parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (6, 3,
'5/7/2007', 'Child of the child 2')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (7, null,
'5/7/2007', '2nd Parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (8, 7,
'5/7/2007', 'Child of 2nd Parent')
insert into workshop (w_id, p_id, s_date, title) values (9, 7,
'5/7/2007', 'Child of 2nd Parent')
go

declare @id smallint
set @id = 1

;with events (w_id, p_id, s_date, title)
as
(
-- the anchor member
select
w_id, p_id, s_date, title
from
workshop
where w_id = @id

-- the recursive member
union all

select
w.w_id, w.p_id, w.s_date, w.title
from
workshop w
-- the key is to join to the CTE
join events e on e.w_id = w.p_id
)

select * from events

drop table workshop
go
```

I have seen various other questions relating to this, but cant see an answer to my problem. The nearset thing is the oracle 'connect by prior' which would be great if I was using an oracle dB! Any ideas?

Cheers,
Jason

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539155/ordering-hierarchy-from-recursive-query-results-in-sql-2005 is the same question.

Comment: Yes, you are right - and thanks to this comment I have found my answer (below!)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer which is that I was joining on the anchor member rather than on the workshop table. Thanks to gjvdkamp for this similar post which made me re-evaluate the 'real' sql statement which was in error.